# How to draw a set-enumeration tree with GraphViz?

Tags: tree, graphviz

I am looking forward to draw a set-enumeration tree using GraphViz, which should look like this:

[image: Image of graph]

Can it be easily done using GraphViz? Is there any existing graphviz examples to produce such a tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A completly naive approach works near perfect. If for some reason graphviz does mess up horizontal ordering there is no real solution.

```
digraph {
 node [shape=plaintext]

 "{}" -> "{1}"
 "{}" -> "{2}"
 "{}" -> "{3}"
 "{}" -> "{4}"

 "{1}" -> "{1,2}"
 "{1}" -> "{1,3}"
 "{1}" -> "{1,4}"

 // ...
}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: I'm not very familiar with graphiz, that is why I'm asking this question. Your graph looks good for what I need to do. However, would it be possible to remove the circles around each node as in the graph shown in my question? If I could do that, it would be perfect.